# JHipster Gateway UI not starting from executable war

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to run Jhipster Gateway (5.0 - springboot 2.0) as an executable war.

Per https://www.jhipster.tech/production/ and https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/, I have:

- Configured the production profile and built using

`mvn -Pprod package`

which looks to successfully build the war with the following directories:

```
META-INF/
org/
org/springframework/
org/springframework/boot/
org/springframework/boot/loader/
org/springframework/boot/loader/util/
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/
app/
content/
i18n/
swagger-ui/
swagger-ui/dist/
swagger-ui/dist/css/
swagger-ui/dist/images/
swagger-ui/dist/lib/
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/com/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/aop/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/aop/logging/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/client/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/config/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/config/apidoc/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/config/audit/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/config/ssl/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/domain/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/gateway/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/gateway/accesscontrol/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/gateway/ratelimiting/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/gateway/responserewriting/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/repository/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/security/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/security/oauth2/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/service/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/service/dto/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/service/mapper/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/web/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/web/rest/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/web/rest/errors/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/web/rest/util/
WEB-INF/classes/com/cheetah/gateway/web/rest/vm/
WEB-INF/classes/config/
WEB-INF/classes/config/liquibase/
WEB-INF/classes/config/liquibase/changelog/
WEB-INF/classes/i18n/
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/templates/
WEB-INF/lib/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.cheetah.gateway/
META-INF/maven/com.cheetah.gateway/gateway/
WEB-INF/lib-provided/
```

- The application log shows it come up successfully (service is running on 7000)

  java -jar gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod

> ```
> ----------------------------------------------------------
>         Application 'gateway' is running! Access URLs:
>         Local:          http://localhost:7000
>         External:       http://192.168.222.33:7000
>         Profile(s):     [prod]
> ----------------------------------------------------------
> ```

but when I try to hit 7000 from a browser, there is no response / UI

```
curl -v localhost:7000
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:7000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 7000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7000
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.3
> Accept: */*
>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

However, I can get the UI to start on 9000 by running

```
yarn start
```

But I don't think this is required for a production environment.  What am I missing?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have anything else listening on port 7000?  Try curling an API endpoint like `/api/profile-info` to see if the backend is reachable

Comment: After shutting down the gateway I had running, I ran netstat -qan and nothing was listening on 7000.  After starting the gateway back up, 7000 was back in use.  I also get the same result with curl -v localhost:7000/api/profile-info as I do with just localhost:7000.

Comment: @JohnB How did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue with an older version of JHipster and have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: In the war file you build, verify that web files (ie .js) are being generated and  added to the /app folder.  I'm not sure the root cause why they weren't initally added in my war, but I think there may have been missing yarn components.   Out of paranaoi, I think I also ran the yarn install tasks in the pom prior to generating the war again (mvn -Pprod package)

Comment: Hi @JohnB, were you able to run the UI with war file only ? can you please guide with steps?

Comment: Change `packaging>jar</packaging>` to `packaging>war</packaging>` in the pom.xml, build your project `mvn install` (which should also install npm and take care of webapp building), and then run `java -jar -0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`.